# Adding extra options to BibTeX (Emacs+AuCTeX)

Tags: bibtex, emacs, auctex

I am trying to customize manually my init file so that, when running BibTeX, the option 
`--min-crossrefs=1` is automatically added. Can this be done just by changing the BibTeX command without modifying all the commands on the `TeX-command-list`?

If this is not possible, perhaps some option can be added at the end of the master file?

Comment: Related: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9993 (at about 1/3 of the quote block).

Comment: @Marijn yes, but no solution there for the manual init file modification.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question. But you can always make a system wide alias, e.g., `alias bibtex='bibtex --min-crossrefs=1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the answer:

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
'(setcdr (assoc "BibTeX" TeX-command-list)
      '("bibtex --min-crossrefs=1 %s"
        TeX-run-BibTeX nil t :help "Run BibTeX with ...")))
```

Proposed here:
http://auctex.gnu.narkive.com/Z8a4meHD/customize-tex-command-list-via-emacs